# Writing to a plist in a LocationManager method

Tags: iphone, plist, cllocationmanager

I am trying to write a latitude value and longitude value to a plist inside a LocationManager method.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
     NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
     NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

     NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"PlayerData" ofType:@"plist"];

     NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

     [plistDict setValue:latitude forKey:@"MyLatitude"];
     [plistDict setValue:longitude forKey:@"MyLongitude"];

     [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];

     myLatitude.text = latitude;
     myLongitude.text = longitude;

    NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);
```

}

For some reason it never writes the value to the plist, but prints out the values correctly.

> NSLog(@"Lat i s:%@ Lon is :%@", latitude, longitude);

What would cause this not to update/write to the plist?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of the filePath and what are the entries in plistDict just before you call writeToFile?

Comment: The method `writeToFile:atomically:` returns a bool if it's successful. Store that bool and use it to know if it worked.

Answer (score 3):

iOS applications are sandboxed, so you can't write to the application bundle.  You need to write to [one of these directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12).  Which one you need to write to depends on what kind of data it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write to the main bundle (may work in simulator but not device).

Try saving the file to the Documents folder instead.

Comment: Be careful abound blindly recommending the Documents directory.  That was a safe bet in the past, but now that iTunes file sharing exists, if you use that directory to store data files that aren't user documents (e.g. cache files, other data files), you could get rejected from the App Store.  The link I provided gives details on alternative directories you can use besides the Documents directory.